# jQuery chain of functions

Tags: jquery, function, asynchronous, chaining

I have such html

```
<div class='mydiv expanded' id='1'>aaa</div>
<div class='mydiv ' id='2'>bbb</div>
<div class='mydiv ' id='3'>ccc</div>
<div class='mydiv ' id='4'>ddd</div>
```

and two functions:

```
function collapse(){
$(document).find('.expanded').removeClass('expanded')
}

function expand(itemid){
$(document).find('.mydiv[id="'+itemid+'"]').addClass('expanded');
}
```

From some other function I call

collapse() //i want to remove all classes "expanded"

expand(3) //i wand to add class "expanded" to an element with id 3

how can I call theese functions one after other - first collapse, then expand.

I have looked on deffered and $.when.then methods, but as I understood they ment to use with ajax calls...

Comment: Neither of these runs asynchronously.  `collapse(); expand(3)` should work fine

Comment: Your code is working perfectly... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was caused by other function, but i had a feeling theese two functions were called at the same time. My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is interpreted and executed line-by-line. Just call your methods out in the order you want them to happen.

$.when.then is needed when working with events, such as DOM or AJAX.